# JMeter json path extractor and Regular expression combination

Tags: regex, jmeter, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I want to extract sys_id for the employee_number does not starting with **"C"**

```
{
    "items": [{
        "sys_updated_on": "2021-01-15 15:04:04",
        "sys_id": "60eaa1dc47870d9132f624846d434a",
        "employee_number": "C89"
    }, {
        "sys_updated_on": "2017-12-08 09:26:49",
        "sys_id": "c57058e8db8689ca52c4be13961974",
        "employee_number": "983"
    }, {
        "sys_updated_on": "2016-04-08 13:25:00",
        "sys_id": "fd413e848716119096ca2d0ebb358e",
        "employee_number": "565"
    }]
}
```

I tried multiple JSON Extractor expressions but no luck

```
$.[?(@.employee_number=~'\d+')].sys_id
$.[?(@.employee_number=~'[0-9]')].sys_id
```

Need both Xpath and Regular expression combination as the JSON contains many other fields and provided JSON is a small part of that.

> I also want to know how to combine the regular expression and JSON
> path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match only numbers in the `employee_number` - try out the following:

```
$.items[?(@.employee_number =~ /\d+/)].sys_id
```

[image]

More information:

- [JsonPath Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators)
- [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)

with regards to what you "also want to know" - one post - one question, however I'll give you some hint:

[image]

Comment: Thanks For the response.

Regarding "also want to know" - I think I confused you My question was "How to add (Combine) a regular expression on Json path"

And I got my answer